# Equivalence of complex bilinear symmetric functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

I ran into the following statement in my lectures but I cannot prove it rigorously.

> **Statement:** Two complex symmetric bilinear forms are equivalent if and only if their ranks are equal.
>
> **Definition:** We say that two symmetric bilinear forms are equivalent if one of them is obtained from the other by linear change
>   of variables.

Before this statement we covered the following nice theorem:

> **Theorem:** For any complex symmetric bilinear functional $\xi$ there is a basis such that the matrix of $\xi$ is diagonal with $1$'s and
>   $0$'s.

So let's try to prove this statement:

$\Rightarrow$ Let $\xi,\eta:V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ be two bilinear functionals.  We can them as the bilinear form:

$\xi(x,y)=X^TAY$ and $\eta(u,v)=U^TBV$, where $X,Y,U,V$ are vector columns and $A=[\xi(e_i,e_j)]$ and $B=[\eta(e_i,e_j)]$ are matrices of $\xi$ and $\eta$, respectively and $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is some basis of $V$.

Since $\xi$ and $\eta$ are equivalent so suppose that WLOG $\eta$ is obtained from $\xi$ by linear change of variables, i.e.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots  \\
y_n  
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
d_{11} & \cdots & {d_{1,2n}} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
d_{2n,1} & \cdots & d_{2n,2n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
\vdots  \\
v_n 
\end{bmatrix}$$ or shotly $\dbinom{X}{Y}=D\dbinom{U}{V}$ where $D$ is a $2n\times 2n$ matrix with $\det D\neq 0$.

And I don't know what to do next.

Can anyone please give the rigorous proof of this statement (both sides) since I have tried it from yesterday and no results. Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric in the case of bilinear forms on $\mathbb C$? Is that $\xi(X,Y) = \xi(Y, X)$ or $\xi(X,Y) = \overline{\xi(Y, X)}$? Are the forms really symmetric or are they actually sesquilinear? I know an answer for sesquilinear forms.

Comment: @AndréPorto, it is just $\xi(x,y)=\xi(y,x)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, why it should be the same linear transformation which takes $X$ to $U$ and $Y$ to $V$. Could you explain it, please? Could you give a separate answer, please? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: I removed my previous comment. I still believe all the work has been done in proving the "nice" Theorem. All we need to worry about is which diagonal matrices with $0,1$ entries are equivalent. Surely it's clear that this happens iff they are equal rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you need to do is to simply use the theorem.

By the theorem, the matrix $A$ is equivalent to a diagonal matrix $D_A$, having only $1$'s and $0$'s, and, by some basic permutation on the elements of the basis, we may suppose that the $1$'s come first in $D_A$. So we have that
$$
A = P_A^T \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] P_A,
$$
where $I_k$ is the identity matrix of size $k=rank(A)=rank(\xi)$, for some matrix $P_A$.

Analogously, we have that
$$
B= P_B^{T}\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] P_B,
$$
with $m=rank(B)=rank(\eta)$.

If $rank(\xi)=rank(\eta)$, then $k=m$, and consequently,
$$
A= P_A^{T}\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]P_A =  P_A^{T}(P_B B P_B^{T})P_A = (P_B^{T}P_A)^T B P_B^{T}P_A.
$$

Conversely, suppose that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are equivalent, that is, there exists some matrix $N$ such that
\begin{align}
A= N^T B N & \Rightarrow \ P_A^{T}\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]P_A = N^T P_B^{T}\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] P_B N \\ &\Rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] = P_AN^T P_B^{T} \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] P_B N P_A^T \\ &
\Rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]= (P_B N P_A^T)^T \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right] P_B N P_A^T.
\end{align}
But then it follows from the uniqueness of the rank of a bilinear form that $rank\left(\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\right)=rank\left(\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\right)$, and consequently, $k=m$, that is, $rank(\xi)=rank(\eta)$.

Comment: First of all, could you give me the definition of equivalent bilinear forms? I wrote that definition above in my post but i don't know how to write it in formulas. I guess this is the reason why i cannot prove this statement.

Comment: Is my reasoning above with $2n\times 2n$ matrix is correct?

Comment: Also in your reasoning you have to replace inverse matrix by transpose, right?

Comment: We say that two bilinear forms $\xi$ and $\eta$ are equivalent if, considering the matrices $A=[\xi(e_i,e_j)]$ and $B=[\eta(e_i,e_j)]$, there exists a matrix $P$ such that $A=P^TBP$.

Comment: Yes. It is true, I have to change the inverse by the transpose. Actually, it would be nice that the Theorem also gave some properties for the diagonalizing basis, precisely, if they imply that the change of variable matrix $P$ associated to this basis satisfies $P^{-1}=P^T$.